# What does this expression of jquery mean $("div[id*='box']")?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does below expression mean it will give me all the div objects which have id containing the word box in it?

```
$("div[id*='box']")
```

Comment: You can test it, right? Yes, it does...

Answer (score 3):

Yes you are correct `$("div[id*='box']")` its mean all div objects which containing `box` word in their `id` attribute.

You can also check `$("div[id^='box']")` - All div objects which `id` attribute starts with box word `Like 'box1', 'box-data'.`

`$("div[id$='box']")` - All div objects which `id` attribute ends with box word `like 'white-box', 'new-box'`

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply, yes :-) Nothing more to add to that, you are correct.